# A variable for the first 8 integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wish to use algebra to (is the term truncate?) the set of positive integers to the first 8 and call it for example 'n'.

In order to define $r_n = 2n$ or similar.

This means:

$$r_0 = 0$$
$$r_1 = 2$$
$$\ldots$$
$$r_7 = 14$$

However there would not be an $r_8$.

edit: Changed "undefined" to "would not be", sorry about this.

Comment: Please format using LaTeX code when possible.

Comment: You're going to have to give some more explanation. I don't see how $r_n=2n$ implies that $r_7=7$ and so on. What do you mean by a "variable for the first 8 integers"?

Comment: I would write something like
$$
  r_i = \begin{cases}
i,& \text{ if }0\leq i\leq 7,
\\
undefined,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Or maybe $r = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb N_0}|_{\overline{0,7}}$ since Russians use the notation $\overline{m,n}:= \{m,m+1,\dots,n-1,n\}$.

Comment: Sorry axblount, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r_n = 2n$ if $0 ≤ n ≤ 7$

Thanks Ilmari Karonen for the correction.

Comment: I've never seen this particular notation, and I'd avoid it because it looks confusingly similar to standard [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).  However, you could simply dispense with the curly braces and write "$r_n = 2n$ if $0 \le n \le 7$", which is perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write

> "Let $r_n = 2n$ for all integers $n$ from $0$ to $7$."

or perhaps

> "Let $r_n = 2n$ for $n \in \{0,1,2,\dotsc,7\}$."

or, using the compact notation suggested by Ilya,

> "Let $r_n = 2n$ for $n \in \overline{0,7}$."

or even, if it's clear from context that $n$ is an integer,

> "Let $r_n = 2n$ for $0 \le n \le 7$."

However, if going with Ilya's notation, be aware that many English-speaking readers may not be familiar with it, so you should define it yourself, e.g. "Let $\overline{n,m} = \{n,\,\dotsc,\,m\}$ denote the set of integers between $n$ and $m$ inclusive."

(Ps. What's wrong with MathJax's rendering of `\overline`, anyway?  The lines in my examples above seem to curve upwards at the ends [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q92QJ.png), while the first — but not the second — one in [Ilya's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185030/a-variable-for-the-first-8-integers#comment426917_185030) curves the other way.)

Comment: I cannot see a curve (neither up not down) on any of the lines. So maybe the problem is in the rendering of your browser (or maybe it's your monitor; do you happen to still have a CRT?)

Comment: @celtschk: No, I have a flat screen display, and I see the ends clearly shifted by one pixel from the middle of the line. [Here's a screenshot.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q92QJ.png) I suppose it might be a browser bug, or something with the OS font rendering. (I'm currently using Chrome on WinXP, which is not my usual browser or OS.)

Comment: @alan2here: The notation $x \in y$ has a well defined meaning: "$x$ is [an element of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)) the set $y$". When used as in "for all $x \in y$", one would typically read it simply as "for all $x$ in $y$".

Comment: I supose even a related statement could be "n∈{0,2,4,…,14}". Mind if I edit "rn=2n if 0≤n≤7" into your answer so that we can unify this into one answer?

Comment: The overline is straight here, on Windows 7 with Firefox 7. Thanks Ilmari Karonen, that makes a lot of sence reguarding ∈. I've removed the comment to which it referred because it was long, wrong and now just in the way.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this [abstract-algebra](/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) and [group-theory](/questions/tagged/group-theory) but it's not entirely clear what you mean.

However, by these tags, perhaps you are referring to $\left(\Bbb Z_8, +\right)$?

In such a case, you have $r_1+r_7 = 1+_8 7 = 8 \mod 8 = 0$. So there is no $r_8$ *per se*; however, the re-definition of the symbols $r_0, r_1, \ldots$ is superfluous.

Comment: I'm not sure about the tags, there wasn't one for algebra.

Comment: It got re-tagged -- there is an [tag:algebra-precalculus] tag that someone put there for you :)